# How to properly handle a Post request to login to a cross-origin localhost api?

Tags: reactjs, spring-security

I am trying to login to my server running at localhost:8080 from a react app running at localhost:3000 but I am having problems sending a post request with username and password

I am using a proxy configuration on my package.json with "proxy": "http://localhost:8080". At first I got stuck at CORS, after messing a bunch with the back-end I think that is fixed. But now my request gets ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS as I am being redirected to localhost:8080/login in a loop for some reason I don't understand.

My spring-security configuration

```
package pos.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MongoUserDetailsService mongoUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(mongoUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

My react-redux login action:

```
import Axios from "axios";

export function login(username, password) {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    let bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.set("username", username);
    bodyFormData.set("password", password);
    const response = await Axios.post("/login", bodyFormData, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
    });
  };
}
```

I am probably doing lots of things wrong here, since I am learning both spring-security and react-redux. But I hope some of you guys would be kind enough to point me in the right direction

Comment: You didn't allow acces to your login page, add `.permitAll()` to `formLogin()`.

Comment: But postman works just fine without it.

Comment: If it is enough that it works with Postman you could delete your question. Your problem is solved.